# recover index in triangular for loops

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, indices

Is there a simple way to recover an index in nested for loops?  For example, in for loops which construct Pascals triangle

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < N-i; ++j)
    index++;
```

is there a way to recover `i` and `j` given only `index`?

Comment: you mean like quotient and remainder?

Comment: @JohnColeman This is slightly more difficult than that because of the variable upper limit of the inner loop. But the answer is 'yes, it is possible'. Worst case scenario, you can replay the two loops and break when you reach the value of index :p But, you can probably do it in constant time, by solving some quadratic equation(s).

Comment: I missed that `i`. Probably need to use the fact that 1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2. A bit of algebra seems to be needed instead of straight number theory. I'm voting the question up as being both interesting and not quite trivial.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks :).  It's part of a computationally intensive GPU kernel repeated fairly often, so I'm hoping to find a closed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding this as a second answer since it is in a different language (now C) and has a more direct approach. I am keeping the original answer since the following code is almost inexplicable without it. I combined my two functions into a single one to cut down on function call overhead. Also, to be 100% sure that it answers the original question, I used the loops from that question verbatim. In the driver function I show explicitly that the output is correct for N = 4 and then stress-test it for N = 10000 (with a total of 100,000,000 passes through the inner loop). I don't have any formal timing code, but it takes about 1 second on my machine to run through and test those 100 million cases. My code assumes a 32-bit `int`. Change to `long` if needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void from_index(int n, int index, int *i, int *j);

int main(void){
    int N;
    int ri,rj; //recovered i,j
    N = 4;
    int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < N-i; ++j){
                    from_index(N,index,&ri,&rj);
                    printf("i = %d, j = %d, index = %d, ",i,j,index);
                    printf("recovered i = %d, recovered j = %d\n",ri,rj);
                    index++;
            }

    //stress test:

    N = 10000;
    index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < N-i; ++j){
                    from_index(N,index,&ri,&rj);
                    if(i != ri || j != rj){
                        printf("Don't post buggy code to Stack Overflow!\n");
                        printf("(i,j) = (%d,%d) but recovered indices are (%d,%d)\n",i,j,ri,rj);
                        return 0;
                    }
                    index++;
            }
    printf("\nAll %d tests passed!\n",N*N);
    return 0;
}

void from_index(int n, int index, int *i, int *j){
    double d;
    d = 4*n*(n+1) - 7 - 8 * index;
    *i = floor((-1 + sqrt(d))/2);
    *j = *i * (*i + 1)/2;
    *j = n*(n+1)/2 - 1 - index - *j;
    *j = *i - *j;
    *i = n - *i - 1;   
}
```

Output:

```
i = 0, j = 0, index = 0, recovered i = 0, recovered j = 0
i = 0, j = 1, index = 1, recovered i = 0, recovered j = 1
i = 0, j = 2, index = 2, recovered i = 0, recovered j = 2
i = 0, j = 3, index = 3, recovered i = 0, recovered j = 3
i = 1, j = 0, index = 4, recovered i = 1, recovered j = 0
i = 1, j = 1, index = 5, recovered i = 1, recovered j = 1
i = 1, j = 2, index = 6, recovered i = 1, recovered j = 2
i = 2, j = 0, index = 7, recovered i = 2, recovered j = 0
i = 2, j = 1, index = 8, recovered i = 2, recovered j = 1
i = 3, j = 0, index = 9, recovered i = 3, recovered j = 0

All 100000000 tests passed!
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case we have

```
index = N+(N-1)+...+(N-i+1) + (j+1) = i(2N-i+1)/2 + (j+1) = -i^i/2 + (2N-1)i/2 + (j+1)
```

with `j` in the interval `[1,N-i]`.

We neglect `j` and regard this as a quadratic equation in `i`. Thus we solve

```
-i^i/2 + (2N-1)i/2 + (1-index) = 0.
```

We approximate `i` to be the greatest out of the two resulting solutions (or the ceil of this value, since neglecting `j` has the effect of lowering the value of `i`).

We then come back to the complete version of the equation and substitute the approximation of the value of `i`. If `j` is outside the interval `[1,N-i]` we increase/decrease the value of `i` and re-substitute until we get a value of `j` in this interval. This loop will probably repeat for a maximum constant number of steps (I suspect a maximum of three steps, but not in the mood to prove it). So this should be doable in a constant number of steps.

As an alternative, we could approximate `j` to be `N/3`, instead of zero. This is approximately the expected value of `j` (over all possible cases), thus the method will probably converge 'faster' at the local search step.

In the general case, you do something very similar, i.e. you solve a fake equation and you perform a local search around the solution.

Comment: Thanks @cobarzan!  The explanation helps, as do @JohnColeman's two code examples.

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to find i,j from the index in the following number pattern:

```
0
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9
```

Since the indices going down the left are the [triangular numbers](https://oeis.org/A000217) of the form k*(k+1)/2. By solving an appropriate quadratic equation I was able to recover the row and the column from the index. *But* -- your loops give something like this:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8
9
```

which is trickier. It might be possible to solve this problem directly, but note that if you subtract each of these numbers from 9 you get

```
9 8 7 6
5 4 3
2 1
0
```

this *is* the original triangle turned upside down and reflected horizontally. Thus -- I can reduce the problem of your triangle to my triangle. The following Python code shows how it works (the only thing not quite obvious is that in Python 3 `//` is integer division). The function `fromIndexHelper` is my solution to my original triangle problem and `fromIndex` is how I shift it to your triangle. To test it I first printed the index pattern for n = 4 and then the corresponding indices recovered by my function `fromIndex`:

```
from math import floor, sqrt

def fromIndexHelper(n,index):
    i = floor((-1+sqrt(1+8*index))/2)
    j = index - i*(i+1)//2
    return i,j

def fromIndex(n,index):
    shift = n*(n+1)//2 - 1
    i,j = fromIndexHelper(n,shift-index)
    return n-i-1,i - j

#test

index = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4-i):
        print(index,end = ' ')
        index +=1
    print('')

print(' ')

index = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4-i):
        print(fromIndex(4,index),end = ' ')
        index +=1
    print('')
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 
9 

(0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) 
(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) 
(2, 0) (2, 1) 
(3, 0)
```